# How to make http://example.com/test.php to http://example.com/index.php?do=test using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a default url `http://example.com/test.php` 
I want to make this url to `http://example.com/index.php?do=test`

`http://example.com/test.php` to `http://example.com/index.php?do=test`

I am using below code, but not working...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.php$ index.php?do=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you even use mod rewrite? You can accomplish this with pure PHP. `if($_GET['do'] == "test") { include "test.php"; }`

Comment: or more dynamic ´´´ include $_GET['do'].".php"; ´´´

Comment: Of coruse mine and @lippoliv answers are vulnerable to full path disclosure and local file inclusion... You should filter the `$_GET['do']` and check if `$_GET['do']` is not an array

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please sir, write full details.

Comment: @lippoliv your approach is very dangerous! Hands off!

Comment: Of course several checks must be done with the input to prepare agains hacks, may I should have wrote that too

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\.php$ index.php?do=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

Comment: index.php includes index.php?do= Please solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?do=$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['do']) && !empty($_GET['do'])){
    include $_GET['do'] . '.php';
} else {
    //include 'index.php';
    //You can include your default file or Error page here
}
?>
```

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello You are in Test Page
</body>
</html>
```

URL : http://localhost/index.php?do=test

Comment: You are including a file which name you haven't even checked. What if someone access `http://localhost/index.php?do=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00`? He could see the content if it's readable and maybe even upload a shell script via user agent and `/proc/self/environ` So check if the `$_GET['do']` contains only letter and numbers so that you prevent directory traversal

^ Stackoverflow changed the ../ to &#‌​47;

Comment: That could not work. index.php includes index.php? Thats the direct opposit of what @LeonaM.Branham asked. `http://localhost/test.php` should be called in browser and PHP should use `index.php?do=test`

Comment: index.php includes index.php?do=  Please solve this problem.

Comment: For `index.php?do=` you can write your code in else part or you can include other files

Comment: i don't understand sir. please give me example.

Comment: when i browse `http;//example.com/index.ph?do=test` url, its showing me with `index.php` content.

Comment: You have to create test.php file for that